# How to schedule to change VM resources in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have 4 VMs in azure and I am trying to set up a schedule to lower the RAMs and CPU cores for after-hours and revert them back to their original size during business hours.

can someone guide me through the steps or share a how-to resource, please? I can't find any documents and I am sure my search key is not correct.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you aren't using [vmss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview)?

Comment: we had a 3rd party doing the migration from the on-premise to azure. I am not sure why they didn't use VMSS though.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by **[@harshavmb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405980/harshavmb)**, you can make use of **VMSS**.

**In Azure, Auto-Scaling is possible if you make use of [Virtual Machine Scale-Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview#next-steps).**

- Virtual Machine Scale-Sets allows you to **automatically scale as resource demand changes.**
- Based on **schedules**, you can create auto scale rules.
- These schedule-based rules allow you to automatically scale the number of VM resources at fixed times.

**To create the Auto-Scale rule, you can make use of following tools:**

- [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-autoscale-powershell)
- [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-autoscale-cli)
- [Azure template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-autoscale-template)

**Otherwise**, you can create an automation account in Azure and execute runbooks as mentioned in below link if helpful:

[Automatically Resize an Azure VM - Automation account](https://petri.com/automatically-resize-azure-vm/)